# Embedding WordPress blog to an existing website

Tags: wordpress, embedding

I have an existing website and I want to know how to embed a WordPress blog to the website, can someone help me out, please?

Comment: `visual-studio-code` and `embedded` tags are completely unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way the other website was built, there's an array of possibilities. However, the path of least resistance (read: zero extra effort) is to install Wordpress on a subdomain (i.e. blog.yoursite.com).

If I misunderstood, and you mean literally displaying one blog post on the other website, you can use the WordPress API or the RSS feed.